# How to verify that the element Y is present between element X and Z in UI using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

How to verify that the element Y is present between element X and Z in UI using selenium java.

Eg: There are three xpath's in a same page. like this

```
"table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[5]/label" Contain Label X
"table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[6]/label" contain Label Y
"table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[7]/label" contain Label Z
```

How to verify whether the Label Y is present between Label X and Label Z using the UI elements

and without using assertText etc.

The xpath's will not be same for the labels it will vary.

Note : The xpath mentioned here is just a sample and not the exact one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use WebElement#getLocation() for each divs with labels and compare their coordinates.